# IBM Worklight - Why sql query used in worklight.js and what is use of that in application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-security, worklight-runtime

We have observed that in worklight.js file below sql query is being used.

```
selectStmt.text = "SELECT * FROM cookies WHERE name=\"" + cookieName + "\"";
```

Please let us know why this is being used and where application is using the same. Is there any security concern on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid only in case of Adobe AIR environments. By design , in case of Adobe AIR , cookies are stored in a SQLLite DB. The query you noted is to retrieve the cookie from this SQLLite DB.

This is not applicable to any other MFP environments ( hybrid or native).
If you are using Adobe AIR environment, this is expected behaviour.